# Silverlight MEF: Replace a XAP

Tags: silverlight, mef

I use DeploymentCatalog and it works just fine until I want to replace a xap with another one.

I tried calling the following methods:

```
        AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Clear();
        Container.ReleaseExports(Container.GetExports<IEnumerable<Export>>());
```

After this the AggregateCatalog has 0 parts in it. But when i download the next xap (it gets downloaded that part i've checked) and call CompositionInitializer.SatisfyImports again the same old xap will be used and the same class will be used again.

How do I get rid of the previously loaded xap entirely?